# Why do you run into problems in counting with distinct sets combined with indistinct sets?

Tags: combinatorics

Say you want to arrange $3$ indistinct students into $8$ seats such that no student is next to each other.

My method:

*x_x_x_x_x*

let the _ denote a seat and $x$ a possible student. There are $5C3$ ways of slotting in the students. Why is this wrong?

Comment: You aren't counting *_s_ _s_ _s* and other stuff.

Comment: The answer is $20$ via stars and bars. But I notice that $5C3 + 5C2$ gives the same answer. Is this merely a coincidence?

Edit: I don't think it is a coincidence. It works for 5 students in 10 seats, 7 students in 12 seats and so on. Now I understand the$ 5C3$ but not the $5C2$. Anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via [Stars and Bars](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) you want the number of non-negative integer solutions to

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = (8-3) = 5$$

where

$$x_2, x_3 ~\text{must be}~ \geq 1.$$

This bijects to

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = (5-2) = 3$$

where

all 4 variables must be non-negative.

By Stars and Bars, the enumeration is

$$\binom{3 + [4-1]}{[4-1]} = \binom{6}{3} = 20.$$

As comment/questioned, $\binom{5}{2} + \binom{5}{3} = \binom{6}{3}.$

Comment: Ok I see. And is Stars and Bars the ONLY method to solve this problem? ie my "gap" method has no hope? Also with the $5\choose2 + 5\choose3$, I was referring to the significance of them separately. ie, for combinatorics to happen, it must've been split up into two cases  namely $5\choose2$ and $5\choose3$ then added

Comment: @user71207 To the best of my **limited** knowledge, the only two ways of *elegantly* solving the problem (without manually counting) is by [Stars and Bars] or [Generating Functions: which I am not familiar with].  **However** there may be an elegant analysis that yields an enumeration of $\left\{\binom{5}{2} + \binom{5}{3}\right\}$ : I simply don't know of any such analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Take out $3$ chairs for the students.

$5$ chairs remain with $6$ gaps where they can be inserted back.

$-C-C-C-C-C-$

Reinsert them in the $6$ gaps in $\binom6 3$ ways

Comment: Thanks! This is a neat logical way that avoids stars and bars (although stars and bars is not bad)

Comment: Stars and bars "not bad" ? Stars and bars is *very good*, but you need to choose "horses for courses"